# How can I write a file from the app to folder Test?

Tags: android

I created the Test folder in the root of the internal memory. How can I write a file from the app to this folder Test? (For example whatsapp.)

```
public class ReadWriteFile {
    public static void ReadWriteFile(String text, Context context) {
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        text = timeFormat.format(currentDate) + text;
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("/test/test.log", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(text);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this code you can create your own directory

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Folder_Name";
        File dir = new File(path);
        try {
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdir();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and using this save your file insdie it

```
String targetPdf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Folder_Name/" + filename;
```

and save your file

```
new FileOutputStream(targetPdf)
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Example to write text file in folder:

```
File mDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "yourFolder");
mDir.mkdir();


try {
        String root_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/";
        File root = new File(root_path);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File f = new File(root_path + "mttext.txt");
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }
        f.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```